# C# Connecting 2 Projects

Tags: c#

I downloaded a Sudoku game in C# and I am trying to connect that game with my project but when I try to connect it with :

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sudoku.SudokuMainForm a = new Sudoku.SudokuMainForm();
        a.Show();
        Hide();
    }
```

It tells me that Sudoku is a namespace but is used like a type.

Here is the part where I have problems with.

```
namespace Sudoku
{

    public class SudokuMainForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form


        }
        Sudoku _newGame = new Sudoku();

        private void btnAnswer_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _showAnswer = false;
            ShowAnswer();
            timer1.Enabled = true;


        }
```

Tried the whole day to fix it,but can't find the solution for my problem.
Hope that you guys have an idea.
Thanks

Comment: what 3rd party api have you downloaded ? and does it have documentation about using ?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ListAlternatives.aspx?aid=12473  that's the one i downloaded. :) All I want is to connect the game with a button so that I can open it in my project when I click on that button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem, you are trying the create instance from name space. Just create instance of any necessary class defined within this name space. you can not create instance with a namespace.

```
Sudoku _newGame = new Sudoku();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is in a namespace called Sudoku, and you are trying to instantiate a class called Sudoku.

You have 2 options, either change your namespace (this is probably simpler, so instead of "namespace Sudoku", try "namespace MySudoku" or something.

Or use:

```
var _newGame = global::<namespace_of_Sudoku_game>.Sudoku();
```

(assuming that your Sudoku class is in SudokuGame then: new global::SudokuGame.Sudoku() )

Comment: I still get the same problem after changing "Sudoku" to "MySudoku".     And where do I put in the "var _newGame = global::<namespace_of_Sudoku_game>.Sudoku();" ?

Comment: replace "Sudoku _newGame = new Sudoku();" with "var _newGame =.. etc

Answer (score 0):

If you use a class inside a namespace with the same name, you need to state both, or use a namespace alias:

```
Sudoku.Sudoku _newGame = new Sudoku.Sudoku();
```

Comment: "The type of namespace name "Sudoku" does not exist in the namespace "Sudoku"(are you missing an assembly reference?)" is what I got after changing it to "Sudoku.Sudoku _newGame = new Sudoku.Sudoku();"

Comment: I changed the namespace to "MySudoku" and the Sudoku.Sudoku to MySudoku.Sudoku but still got the same Error.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Right Click on Solution>Add>Existing Project>Selecting the.csproj>Right Click on the first project>Add References>Selected the added project> and then the normal binding.
Thanks for everyone help.